# Excel VBA Suddenly Goes To Design Mode during Macro Runtime

Tags: vba, excel

Hope someone help me with this problem.

I have a subroutine that will copy my data from this workbook to another existing workbook(Report Workbook).

When I try to run the code, during run-time once it opens the Report Workbook it suddenly stops and I've notice that it goes to design mode. Thus, hindering the execution of the routine.

But when I try to put a break point on the subroutine and continue it again. It executes without problem. This seems a bit odd.

I'm a bit out of the corner trying to figure this out.

So far this are the troubleshooting steps that I've tried.

1. Tried to run the Workbook in another machine.
2. I have tried deleting all the Workbook_Open on the Report Workbook.
3. Tried to delete all the Macro Codes on the Report Workbook.
4. Insert an error handler. Unfortunately, no error is presented.
5. Tried to delete the DoEvents code on the subroutine.

But still no luck. It stops the code from executing.

```
Private Sub TransferRawData()
Dim wsPTRawData As Worksheet, wbPTWorkBook As Workbook, wsOutputRaw As Worksheet
Dim filePath As String, FileName As String, ptTargetRow As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.StatusBar = "Exporting All Raw Data... Please wait a moment..."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
FileName = filePath & pt_FileName

Set wbPTWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileName, UpdateLinks:=0, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
DoEvents
Set wsPTRawData = wbPTWorkBook.Worksheets(pt_ProdRawSheet)
Set wsOutputRaw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(merger_prodOutputSheet)

ptTargetRow = wsPTRawData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If lastRow(wsOutputRaw, "A") > 1 Then wsOutputRaw.Range("A2:F" &    lastRow(wsOutputRaw, "A")).Copy wsPTRawData.Range("A" & ptTargetRow)

wbPTWorkBook.Close True

Set wsOutputRaw = Nothing
Set wsPTRawData = Nothing
Set wbPTWorkBook = Nothing

End Sub
```

BTW, I have 3 set of workbook that uses the above code. All of them will copy the data on the Report Workbook. But all of them are having trouble in executing  the transfer routine.

For additional Information. Once I run the routine and it executes the Workbooks.Open Event. Here is the screenshot of the VBA Project Window and Excel Window.

[image]

Comment: is there an error showing? ... please post a screenshot if you can

Comment: hi @jsotola, It didn't appear any error messages. But I added a screenshot of my screen to give you a better overview on my problem.

Comment: Can you add error catches in there and output the error message? Sometimes there are hidden error messages

Comment: Don't know if this is all of the code, but the Calculation and EnableEvents settings are persistent - you should be setting them back before your code exits.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams yeah, actually i can omit all those performance enhancer settings in this routine. Cause before I execute all the routines in my projects I have set it all up and set them back again. I just added all those settings on this routine for additional reference.

Comment: Hi @Maldred, any thoughts how could I catch this certain error? Sorry but I have no idea.

Comment: What *Line* is it on when it stops?  If you are unsure, use ctrl-L to get the stack list and double-click the top entry.  This should be you current statement.

Comment: My offhand guess is that the `DoEvents` is allowing the Report Workbook to run its own startup code that is doing something weird that is causing it to stop when it returns.  I'd advise checking your Debug settings and what code may be executing in the Report workbook.

Comment: Hi thank you for all the suggestion, i have tried to applied it all. But still no luck. I have updated the post to save as reference for all the troubleshooting guides that I have done so far.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I think the code stops on the line(Set wbPTWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileName, UpdateLinks:=0, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)) when the routine calls the other workbook. Cause once the Report Workbook opens, it immediately goes to design mode. Thus, stopping the execution of my current routine.

Comment: what does ctrl-L show?

Comment: Unfortunately it shows nothing.

Comment: screenshot of the toolbars is no help. you might as well remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I had the same problem, tried everything, nothing worked.
Interesting is that I was opening .xlsx file, and still it was going into the break mode.
Only when I changed CTRL+SHIFT to ALT-CTRL it worked.
Still do not understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi For Reference of others that will encounter this issue on the future.

The code itself doesn't have anything to do with the error.

After a lot of time investigating this error. I have found out that the culprit is the shortcut key that I have assigned on the Macro itself.

I have assigned a **CTRL+SHIFT** Key on the macro thus hindering the other macro of the other workbook that its opening.

Going forward, I made configuration on my Macro shortcut key and avoided the **Shift** key. As a result, the subroutine do what it needs to supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Add an error handler in here and see if there are any errors that aren't being caught properly

```
Private Sub TransferRawData()
Dim wsPTRawData As Worksheet, wbPTWorkBook As Workbook, wsOutputRaw As Worksheet
Dim filePath As String, FileName As String, ptTargetRow As Long

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.StatusBar = "Exporting All Raw Data... Please wait a moment..."
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
FileName = filePath & pt_FileName

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set wbPTWorkBook = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=FileName, UpdateLinks:=0, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
DoEvents
Set wsPTRawData = wbPTWorkBook.Worksheets(pt_ProdRawSheet)
Set wsOutputRaw = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(merger_prodOutputSheet)

ptTargetRow = wsPTRawData.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If lastRow(wsOutputRaw, "A") > 1 Then wsOutputRaw.Range("A2:F" &    lastRow(wsOutputRaw, "A")).Copy wsPTRawData.Range("A" & ptTargetRow)

wbPTWorkBook.Close True

Set wsOutputRaw = Nothing
Set wsPTRawData = Nothing
Set wbPTWorkBook = Nothing


ErrHandlerSave:
    Debug.Print Chr(13) & "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated on Saving" _
        & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) & Err.Description
End Sub
```

You'll see an error message come up in the `Immediate` window at the bottom of the VBA code. If you don't have it up or unsure how to show it [LOOK HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy.aspx)